# Python : email address's are not visible

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send email to  multiple people. My code is working , people are getting the emails but somehow the the To: field is showing as "undisclosed-recipients" in email clients , How can I make them visible  there?

Also Is there is any way to Add BCC here?

here's my code:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText as text
    import smtplib
    import shutil
    import sys, traceback
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart


    lines = ['xyz: test@example.com, xyz1: test1@example.com, HJH: 
    test9@example.com, TESTING: gtest1@example.com, GHT: test1@example.com, TYR: 
    test1@example.com', 'GHZ: test8@example.comm, NUY: test5@example.com']
    w1=[]
    sender = ['xyz@example.com']
    for l in lines:
            to = {}
            body = []
            groups = []
            parts = re.split('(.+?)\:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9@\._\-]+),\s+(.*)$', l)
            master = parts[1]
            master_email = parts[2]
            subgroups_line = parts[3]
    subgroup_parts = re.split(',\s*', subgroups_line)
    to[master_email] = 1;
    for sp in subgroup_parts:
        (subgroup_name, subgroup_email) = sp.split(': ')
        groups.extend((subgroup_name,":",subgroup_email+"\n"))
        to[subgroup_email] = 1
                var1 = ''.join(groups)
#                print var1
        print 'email to: ' + ','.join(to.keys())
        receivers =(to.keys())
        header = 'To:' + ",".join(receivers)
        template1=open('template1','r')
        template2=open('template2','r')
        print groups 
        print master
        if master in groups:
          m=text("ANY TEXT1)
        else: 
          m=text("ANY TEXT2")
        m['Subject'] = 'XXXXXXXX'
        try:
          smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
          smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers,  m.as_string())
          template1.close()
          template2.close()
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
          print "Unable to send email"
```

Update:
I was able to  add To: as well as BCC: functionality. Please ignore this :-)

Thanks for help anyways!

Comment: K I was able to figure out why it was showing   undisclosed-recipients. It was missing header so I added m['To'] = ', '.join(receivers)  and now its working. Only part missing is BCC:

Comment: Sorry  BCC is also working now..I just dont have to add that in header :-)

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it. You deserve the upvotes - helped me fix my problem!